# Can't enable nvidia profile on nvidia-prime, ubuntu 15.04

Tags: hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime, 15.04

This is a bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1412057

```
#prime-select nvidia

Info: the current alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
Info: selecting nvidia-346 for the nvidia profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
```

and

```
#prime-switch nvidia

/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
```

Altough it seems to be switching to nvidia profile, after reboot mesa is again selected.

Some info

- Computer: Lenovo T440s (intel and nvidia dual graphic card)
- Ubuntu: 15.04 64bit
- Kernel: 3.18.0-9
- Nvidia-prime: 0.8.1
- Nvidia-346-updates: 346.57-0ubuntu4

Is there any way that I can enable the nvidia card? I don't need the intel gpu, I always use the nvidia gpu.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this affects me as well. I have tried drivers 340 and 346, I have installed bumblebee, primus and bumblebee-nvidia, I edited the bumblebee config file (etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf) replacing nvidia-current with nvidia-346 or nvidia-340 and editing Driver to Driver=nvidia and no positive results. But someone said that this worked for him, maybe it wasn’t an hybrid card.

I found out it is possible to run it if after doing the above procedure, run application with: vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus, maybe just optirun in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall Nvidia and Intel drivers:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia* intel*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get autoremove intltool*
```

After this removes, install Nvidia and Intel both from control center/additional Drivers.

Next run terminal and install `prime-indicator` to switch easily.

```
$ sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

Done.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Enjoy.

Kamran Golpayegani